# Assistance converting .NET 5 into .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am trying to seed my database and add roles to my ASP.NET Core Web Application. In the tutorial I am following, it advised to add the following to the Configure() method:

```
    app.UseAuthentication();
MyIdentityDataInitializer.SeedData(userManager, roleManager);
```

I had no issues with the first line, but with the second, I am getting an error saying userManager and roleManager doesn't exist which makes sense because if i were using .NET 5 my configure method would've looked like this and been fine:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
IHostingEnvironment env, 
UserManager<MyIdentityUser> userManager, 
RoleManager<MyIdentityRole> roleManager)
{
    ...
    app.UseAuthentication();

    MyIdentityDataInitializer.SeedData(userManager, roleManager);

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
      routes.MapRoute(
      name: "default",
      template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

But in .NET 6 I'm not sure how to.

Can someone advise on this please?

Comment: Are you trying to do this with the minimal API code that doesn't have StartUp.cs? I'm not sure how you do it with that but you can still use the old Startup.cs way of doing things and have the same configure method I think ....at least I've got a Configure method in Startup my .net 6 project and I'm doing DI there

Comment: This might be of interest: https://www.codemag.com/Article/2201081/Minimal-APIs-in-.NET-6

Comment: @tappetyclick When I created the application it didn't come with a startup.cs, didn't realise I could add it back in - ill try that thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .NET 6, Microsoft has removed the `Startup.cs` class where your `Configure()` method was previously defined.  Instead, configuration of both the DI service container (which was done previously in the `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection)`) method) and the AspNet Core Application Builder are done directly in `Program.cs`

Now since there is nothing automatically calling the `Configure()` method for you (and injecting those values for you), you'll have to get references to those objects yourself using the ServiceProvider.  Your `Program.cs` will probably look something like this:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// add services that were previously added in ConfigureServices()

var app = builder.Build();

var userManager = app.Services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<MyIdentityUser>>();
var roleManager = app.Services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<MyIdentityRole>>();
MyIdentityDataInitializer.SeedData(userManager, roleManager);

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

*Edit: To fix your error, (and as the link @tappetyclick directed you to explains), you'll need to first create a scope in order to get references to your `UserManager` and `RoleManager` objects:

```cs
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<MyIdentityUser>>();
    var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<MyIdentityRole>>();
    MyIdentityDataInitializer.SeedData(userManager, roleManager);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am getting an error when running it: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager'1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' from root provider. I'm not sure why, do you have any ideas?

Comment: This seems be doing roughly the same as you (seeding) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72447401/cannot-resolve-scoped-service-from-root-provider-in-asp-net-core-6 or try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52487989/cannot-resolve-scoped-service-microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanager1ident